# Форматирование двухмерного массива с числами

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы, вывод

Имеется двухмерный массив с числами. Нужно отформатировать вывод таким образом, чтобы между соседними элементами с разными значениями стояла звездочка `"*"`, а если значения равны, то пробел `" "`, по горизонтали и по вертикали. Пример:

```
*********
*1 1*3*4*
***** * *
*2 2*3*4*
*********
```

Числа могут быть многозначными.

Пробовал разные вещи, например создать новый массив размера `[Nx2][Mx2]` или `System.out.format`, но в итоге оно не форматирует, как нужно. Как можно это реализовать?

```java
private static void changeColumn(int[][] secondLayerArr, int n, int m) {
  String[][] finalLayerArr = new String[n * 2 - 1][m];
  int finalLayerRow = -2;
  // second layer output
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    finalLayerRow += 2;

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if (j < m - 1) {
        if (secondLayerArr[i][j] != secondLayerArr[i][j + 1]) {
          finalLayerArr[finalLayerRow][j] = (secondLayerArr[i][j]) + "*";
          // System.out.print(secondLayerArr[i][j] + "*");
        } else {
          finalLayerArr[finalLayerRow][j] = (secondLayerArr[i][j]) + " ";
          // System.out.print(secondLayerArr[i][j]);
        }
      } else {
        finalLayerArr[finalLayerRow][j] = (secondLayerArr[i][j]) + "*";
        // System.out.print(secondLayerArr[i][j]+"*");
      }
    }
  }
  printColumn(finalLayerArr);
}
```

```java
public static void changeRow(String[][] finalLayerArr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < finalLayerArr[0].length; i++) {
    System.out.print("***");
  }
  System.out.println();

  for (int i = 0; i < finalLayerArr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
    for (int j = 0; j < finalLayerArr[0].length; j++) {
      if (finalLayerArr[i][j] == null) {
        if (finalLayerArr[i - 1][j].equals(finalLayerArr[i + 1][j])) {
          finalLayerArr[i][j] = " ";
        } else {
          finalLayerArr[i][j] = "*";
        }
      }
      System.out.printf("%2s", finalLayerArr[i][j], "");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Оно показывает примерно то, что надо, но не форматирует как таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно собрать массив строк, состоящий из чисел из первого массива и их соседних элементов, т. е. звёздочек и пробелов. Отформатировать их по необходимости, т. е. дополнить ведущими нулями и соответствующим количеством соседних элементов. Для каждой строки создаем два массива строк, т. е. элементы с их соседями по горизонтали и промежуточный массив с соседями по вертикали, плюс ведущие и замыкающие строки со звёздочками. Выстраиваем в один массив по вертикали и объединяем элементы в одну строку по горизонтали:

```java
int[][] arr1 = {
        {1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 8, 75},
        {2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8},
        {3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 5, 2, 8}};

// формат чисел, количество цифр
int s = 2;

// форматированное представление
// массива с соседними элементами
String[] arr2 = IntStream
        // обходим индексы строк массива,
        // плюс ведущая строка со звёздочками
        .range(-1, arr1.length)
        // для каждой строки создаём два массива строк:
        // соседи по горизонтали и по вертикали
        .mapToObj(i -> {
            // предполагаем, что длины строк одинаковы
            int length = arr1[0].length * s * 2 - s + 2;
            String[] asterisks = new String[length];
            Arrays.fill(asterisks, "*");
            if (i == -1)
                // ведущая строка со звёздочками
                return Stream.of(null, asterisks);
            else
                // обходим индексы элементов строк,
                // добавляем звездочки между соседями с разными
                // значениями и пробелы, если значения одинаковые
                return Stream.of(IntStream.range(0, arr1[i].length)
                            // соседи по горизонтали
                            .mapToObj(j -> {
                                // форматированное представление
                                // элемента строки с ведущими
                                // нулями по необходимости
                                String val = String.format(
                                        "%0" + s + "d", arr1[i][j]);
                                if (j == 0)
                                    // ведущая звездочка
                                    val = "*" + val;
                                if (j == arr1[i].length - 1)
                                    // замыкающая звездочка
                                    val += "*";
                                else
                                    // соседний элемент
                                    val += arr1[i][j] == arr1[i][j + 1] ?
                                            " ".repeat(s) : "*".repeat(s);
                                return val;
                            }).toArray(String[]::new),
                        // второй массив
                        (i == arr1.length - 1) ?
                            // замыкающая строка со звёздочками
                            asterisks :
                            // соседи по вертикали
                            IntStream.range(0, arr1[i].length)
                                .mapToObj(j -> {
                                    String val = "";
                                    if (j == 0)
                                        // ведущая звездочка
                                        val = "*";
                                    // соседний элемент
                                    val += (arr1[i][j] == arr1[i + 1][j] ?
                                            " ".repeat(s) : "*".repeat(s));
                                    if (j == arr1[i].length - 1)
                                        // замыкающая звездочка
                                        val += "*";
                                    else
                                        // промежуточные звёздочки
                                        val += "*".repeat(s);
                                    return val;
                                }).toArray(String[]::new));
        }).flatMap(Function.identity())
        // пропускаем первый null
        .skip(1)
        // Stream<Stream<String>>
        .map(Arrays::stream)
        // объединяем элементы в одну строку
        .map(stream -> stream.collect(Collectors.joining()))
        .toArray(String[]::new);

// вывод
Arrays.stream(arr2).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:

```
****************************************
*01  01**03  03**04**06**05**06**08**75*
*************  **  ******  ******  *****
*02  02  02**03**04**05  05  05**08  08*
*****************************  ******  *
*03  03**05  05**06**07  07**05**02**08*
****************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно есть решение, которое короче

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{1, 1, 3, 4}, {2, 2, 3, 4}};
    int w = (arr[0].length * 2);
    int h = (arr.length * 2);
    String result = join("*", w + 1) + "\n";
    for (int y = 1; y < h; y++) {
        result += "*";
        for (int x = 1; x < w; x++) {
            if (y % 2 == 0) {
                if (x % 2 == 0) {
                    result += "*";
                } else {
                    result += arr[(y - 1) / 2][x / 2] ==
                            arr[(y + 1) / 2][x / 2] ? " " : "*";
                }
            } else {
                if (x % 2 == 0) {
                    result += arr[y / 2][(x - 1) / 2] ==
                            arr[y / 2][(x + 1) / 2] ? " " : "*";
                } else {
                    result += arr[y / 2][x / 2];
                }
            }
        }
        result += "*\n";
    }
    result += join("*", w + 1);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

```java
private static String join(String str, int i2) {
    String s = str;
    for (int i = 1; i < i2; i++) {
        s += str;
    }
    return s;
}
```